# factor an integer as the sum of 20 different random integers greater than zero with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, random, integer

I have a small problem that I can't solve.

I would like, with a JavaScript code, to decompose an integer, such as the sum of several integers greater than zero and different from each other.

For now, I have managed to create the code below.
The problem is that it generates integers greater than zero, which however can be equal to each other.

How can I make them different from each other?

**JavaScript code**

```
const targetNumber = 40; 
const numTerms = 20; 

const result = BreakDownNumber(targetNumber, numTerms);
console.log("number to break down:", targetNumber);
console.log("random numbers:", result);

 
 function BreakDownNumber(targetNumber, numTerms) {

     let numbers = [];

     function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
       return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
     }
  
     let sum = 0;
     for (let i = 0; i < numTerms - 1; i++) {
       let randomNumber = getRandomNumber(1, targetNumber - sum - (numTerms - i - 1));
       numbers.push(randomNumber);
       sum += randomNumber;
    }
  
     // Last number
     numbers.push(targetNumber - sum);
  
     return numbers;
   }
```

I probably have to change everything, but I don't know.
I know it's a trivial question but I'm truly a beginner. ;)

I gladly accept any advice and help.

Thanks a lot to everyone.

Happy programming!

Comment: do you want allways different numbers? what amount of numbers do you want?

Comment: Solutions may take quite some time to run

Comment: I suggest replacing "factor" with "decompose" or "express" in the title of the post. "Factor an integer" *always* mean write the integer as a product, not as a sum.

Comment: @NinaScholz, yes the problem is that i want all different numbers.

Comment: @Stef, thank you for the advice and sorry for my bad English ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a while loop to generate a random number, and if it does not conform to the rules do not increment i

Note:

the last number cannot mathematically conform to your rules if you have random numbers, it's just up to chance + the last number goes 1 over the numTerms (I left it like that in case it was intentional)

(I changed the numbers to make it run quicker)

```js
const targetNumber = 10; 
const numTerms = 2; 

const result = BreakDownNumber(targetNumber, numTerms);
console.log("number to break down:", targetNumber);
console.log("random numbers:", result);

 
 function BreakDownNumber(targetNumber, numTerms) {

     let numbers = [];

     function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
       return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
     }
  
     let sum = 0;
     let i = 0
     while (i < numTerms) {
       let randomNumber = getRandomNumber(1, targetNumber - sum);
       if (!(numbers.includes(randomNumber))) {
            numbers.push(randomNumber);
            sum += randomNumber;
            i++
        }
    }
  
     // Last number
     numbers.push(targetNumber - sum);
  
     return numbers;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The smallest sum of n different positive integers is 1+2+...+n = n(n+1)/2. So for a given n, if the target is smaller than that, there is no solution.

Otherwise, one valid solution is 1, 2, ..., n-1, (target - n).

Answer (score 1):

There is known statistical distribution which generates **k** random numbers summed up to **n** - [Multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution). It is distribution property such that sampled array of numbers sum to **n**.

Sample and then you could check for uniqueness.

Not knowing much of Javascript, and using https://github.com/jacobmenick/sampling as sampling routine, here is some pseudocode

```
function BreakDownNumber(targetNumber, numTerms) {
    probs = numTerms*[1]; // probabilities

    while (true) {
        numbers = SJS.Multinomial(targetNumber, probs);
        if (areUnique(numbers))
            return numbers;
    }

    return [];
}
```